# Linux Log file for signals

Tags: linux, logs, signals

Just wondering any log file I can check in Debian if my colleague sigstop or sigterm my process during I'm away?

I've checked syslog, message files. But wasn't able to find any relevant log.

Or any required settings to log this signals to log files?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such log. Linux kernel tracing facilities (`sysdig`,
`systemtap`, etc) could likely create such a log, but if your colleagues have
permission to `STOP` or `TERM` your processes, they could likely also
disable any custom logging (if they know about it or find it).